# Call to a member function delete() on null multiple delete

Tags: php, html, laravel

I made a delete multiple function, but I have some troubles with. When I select 2 checkboxes, and submit it but after that I'm redirected to `url/article/delete/559` with `null` message at `dd($article_id)`.

**Here is my controller function:**

```
     public function deleteArticles (requ $request){
     $article_id = $request['news_id'];
     dd($article_id);
   DB::table('contacts')
        ->whereIn('id', $article_id)
        ->delete();

    return back();

  }

  public function delete($id)
  {

      $careerSolution = \App\Contact::find($id);
      $careerSolution->delete();


    return redirect(URL::previous());
  }
```

**Here is my routes**

```
Route::get('article/delete/{id?}', 'ContactController@delete');
Route::post('noticeboard/{page?}', array('as' => 'noticeboard', 'uses' => 'ContactController@deleteArticles'));
```

**Here is my view**

```
<div id="my_contacts_grid" class="profile-edit tab-pane fade in active" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0;">



    <dl class="dl-horizontal">





        <?php $count_user = 0; ?>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    @if($count_user == 0)
                        <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    @endif


                    <?php $count_user++; ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ action ('ContactController@deleteArticles')}}">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="profile-blog" style="padding: 0px">
                            <img class=" noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $user->profile_picture }}" alt="" style="margin-left: 20px;margin-top: 15px;">
                            <div style="top: 35px;position: relative;right: 85px;margin-bottom:30px" class="name-location">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-xs-12" >
                                                        <li>
                                    <strong style="display: inline-table !important">
                                        <h3>@if($user->role[0]->slug == "individuals")
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;left: 60px;position: relative;top: 2px;" class="icon-user"></i>

                                    @elseif($user->role[0]->slug =='organizations')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;left: 60px;position: relative;top: 2px" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
                                    @endif<a style="font-size: 16px;left: 60px;position: relative;top: 2px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}"> {{ $user->username }}</a></h3></strong>

                                                        <p style="right: 10px;position: relative;width: 110%">
                                                <i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i><strong style="display: inline-table !important;font-size: 13px">Location : </strong> {{ $user->country->country }} <span class="{{$user->country->flag}}"></span><br>
                                                <i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-notebook fa-"></i><strong style="display: inline-table !important;font-size: 13px">Industry : </strong> {{ $user->industry->industry }}<br>

                                                @if($user->role[0]->slug == "individuals")
                                                    @foreach($user->career_path as $career_path)
                                                        <i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-speedometer"></i><strong style="display: inline-table !important;font-size: 13px">Function : </strong> {{ $career_path->functions->function }}
                                                        @break;
                                                    @endforeach
                                                @elseif($user->role[0]->slug =='organizations')

                                                    <i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-frame fa-"></i><strong style="display: inline-table !important;font-size: 13px">Organization : </strong> {{ $user->organization_type->organization_type }}<br>
                                                @endif
                                                </p>
 </li>
                                         </ul>
                                         </div>


                            <hr>

                        <ul class="social-icons social-icons-color" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="social-cu" id="social-cu">

                                        <li class="facebook_share" link="{{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}" style="left: 5px;position: relative">
                                            <img id="social-im" class="img-responsive social_whatsapp" src="{{ asset('/assets/img/icons/social/facebook-test.png') }}" alt="" style="height: 22px !important">
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="twitter_share" link="{{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}" name="{{ $user->username }} Workstickers Profile" style="left: 15px; position: relative">
                                            <img id="social-im" class="img-responsive social_whatsapp" src="{{ asset('/assets/img/icons/social/twitter-test.png') }}" alt="" style="height: 22px !important">
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="whatapp_share" link="{{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}" name="{{ $user->username }} Workstickers Profile" style="left: 25px;position: relative">
                                            <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}" style="top: 5px; position: relative">
                                                <img id="social-w" class="img-responsive social_whatsapp" src="{{ asset('/assets/img/icons/social/Whatsapp.png') }}" style="height: 25px !important" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>

                            <ul class="list-inline share-list" style="text-align: center;padding-bottom:10px">
                                <li>
                                    <input name="news_id[]" type="checkbox"   class="checkbox_news"  value="{{$user->id}}"/>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('invitations-reject').'/'.$user->id }}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="send-contact-message "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ssend_message_touser_{{ $user->id }}">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send message</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="share-link">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if($count_user == 2)
                        </div>
                        <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>
                    @endif

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="ssend_message_touser_{{ $user->id }}" role="dialog"  style="margin-top:40px;">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal email-->
                            <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 0px;top: 200px">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="mt-5">Send message to {{ $user->username }}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    {!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal sky-form sky-changes-3','url' => 'message-send']) !!}

                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="display: none">To</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input style="display: none" class="form-control" type="email" name="username" value="{{ $user->username }}" readonly>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="contact_user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ url('') }}/{{ $user->username }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <fieldset>

                                            <section>
                                                <label class="label">Subject</label>
                                                <label class="input">
                                                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                                                </label>
                                            </section>

                                            <section>
                                                <label class="label">Message</label>
                                                <label class="textarea">
                                                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
                                                    <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
                                                </label>
                                            </section>
                                        </fieldset>




                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" style="bottom: 2px;position: relative">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-primary">Send message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- end email Modal -->

                    @endforeach
                    <a href="{{ url('article/delete/'.$user->id) }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this article?');">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </form>
{!! $users->render() !!}

    </dl>

</div>
<style>
            #social-cu{
            width: 120px !important;
            left: 200px;
            top: -25px !important;
        }
        #social-im{
    float: left;
    width: 22px;
    margin-right: 0px;
        }
        #social-w{
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px;
        }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.initScrollBar();
        RegForm.initRegForm();
        Datepicker.initDatepicker();
        CheckoutForm.initCheckoutForm();
        StyleSwitcher.initStyleSwitcher();



    $(".send-contact-message").live('click', function(){

        var user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
        $('#ssend_message_touser_'+user_id).modal('show');
    });


    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // StyleSwitcher.initStyleSwitcher();

        $("#select_all").click(function () {
                    $(".checkbox_news").prop('checked',true);
            });

            $("#deselect_all").click(function () {
                    $(".checkbox_news").prop('checked',false);
            });


    });
</script>
```

So, when I check a checkbox or multiple, I should be able to have a multiple delete.

Comment: fine but the error isn't coming from that form, it is coming from your hyperlink to delete the article for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$careerSolution = \App\Contact::find($id);
```

When it's return null then you get error `Call to a member function delete()`.

Use this One:

```
\App\Contact::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: it would be better to just handle the condition of not finding the record, calling delete on the builder bypasses the model completely (no soft delete, no model events, etc..)